# Getting value from an array

Tags: php, arrays, api

I have an array I call with an api connection.

```
["data"]=>
  object(stdClass)#212 (3) {
    ["status_code"]=>
    int(200)
    ["data"]=>
    object(stdClass)#211 (3) {
      ["days"]=>
      int(30)
      ["total_clicks"]=>
      int(6)
      ["clicks"]=>
      array(30) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#215 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
          ["day_start"]=>
          int(1466395200)
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#216 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
          ["day_start"]=>
          int(1466308800)
        }
```

I try to get the first

```
["data"]=>
  object(stdClass)#212 (3) {
    ["status_code"]=>
    int(200)
    ["data"]=>
    object(stdClass)#211 (3) {
      ["days"]=>
      int(30)
      ["total_clicks"]=>
      int(6)
      ["clicks"]=>
      array(30) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#215 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
```

I try to do so with the following function (the array itself is stored in the "$data" variable):

```
function currentClicks($data)
        {
            $path = $data->data->data->clicks;
            foreach ($path as $key => $item) {
                $array[] = [$item->clicks[0]];
            }
            return json_encode($array);
        }
```

And I echo it in a `<h1>` tag: `<h1><?php echo currentClicks($data); ?></h1>`
The problem is that instead of displaying the value (which is the number 0) I get an error in console displaying

```
[[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null],[null]]
```

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: How is this off topic? He clearly has a bug in traversing the object.

Answer (score -2):

`Clicks` is still an object, you still haven't reached the "bottom" of the object to display a primitive.

So for example it should be:

```
 $array[] = [$item->clicks[0]['clicks']];
```

Comment: Just curious what the downvoters see :)